# Remove command outline (colorbox or frame) in the pdf of Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

When I am saving the **Jupyter** notebook as **pdf** (PDF via LaTeX), **color text box** or **frame** appeared around some **command**. You can see the following images. How to get rid of this?

## Jupyter notebook,

[image: Image of Jupyter notebook]

## Exported pdf

you can see coloured frame each letter in line `[1]` , `[2]` and `[5]`
[image: exported pdf]

### How to remove the coloured text box ?